# CoordinatorLayout's content overflows

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an issue with CoordinatorLayout Fragment which content does not in that its container when i switch fragment.

It is a Tab based application without ViewPager.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <com.toto.views.widgets.TabLayoutWrapper
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/deepGreen">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/tab_indicator"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/darkGreen"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/deepGreen"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </com.toto.views.widgets.TabLayoutWrapper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each of my tabs are CoordinatorLayout. I hide the recyclerView if there's not item and show a beautiful "empty drawing"

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.toto.views.recyclerView.ConversationListRecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/conversation_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/palerGreen">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:src="@drawable/grp_kevin_harry_clap"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/purple">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/wait"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
        style="@style/FloatingActionButton.Plus"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Both LinearLayout are simplified. I have found a way to make it fit inside the container with:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.frame);
        CoordinatorLayout coordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) getView();
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
        behavior.onNestedFling(coordinator, appbar, null, 0, -1000, true);
    }
```

But the thing is, we see the entire view moving while changing tab. I check the size of the CoordinatorLayout which is equal to the entire screen minus the TabLayout. So the content is not well designed.
Any suggestion to fix the "animation" to "no animation" or is there another way to hide a RecyclerView with a ViewGroup ? 
I target at least the API 19.

PS: Changing the architecture for a ViewPager is not an option yet.

Comment: I can't reproduce the fix